# Rescaling a radio image

Tags: radio-astronomy

After a radio image has been cleaned it is advised that the fluxes be rescaled if the source is near the galactic plane. Can someone explain why this is needed?

Comment: Please also state which algorithm you use for image cleaning. Not all of them preserve flux, so rescaling results makes sense in some cases.

Comment: @uhoh I've read this in quite a few papers but the problem they do not state the why it is done. I have an idea that it has something to do with the difference in system temperatures corresponding to the flux calibrator and the source observation but I'm not exactly able to understand the whole thing.

Comment: @samcarter I am using AIPS for cleaning the image